# UITextField content type password some time change the state while entering password

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am using `Xocde` - 10.1 and added a `UITextField` in storyboard

[image]

Properties of the text field are shown on the following  screen shot -

[image]

When I'm entering a password, it shows me a warning 'Strong password' and user interaction is being disabled for the text field.

[image]

Additional explanation - the text field works fine most of the time while I am entering the text inside it. But sometimes a text that should be hidden is being shown in the left side of the text field (like on screenshot above). If I reload the view, then I will be able to edit it. Otherwise - I won't be able to continue editing it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please edit it and provide more explanation about expected behavior?

Comment: I am also not understand why it is happening ... But this will happen with Simulator most of the time.

Comment: I've edited your question. I hope I understood the issue properly. Please add your view controller's code. Probably issue is somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the iOS 12 Password AutoFill behavior. I'd try removing the `ContentType` of `Password` on the field for simulator only if it's causing you problems there.  On a device I suspect you'd get the expected behavior and be able to interact as outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow).

You may also have to move the show/hide password image out of the text field if you want to support strong password autofill.